# When a Service stops?

Tags: .net, service

I am looking into creating a service. I don't want to get into the details too much but basically it will convert bin files to tifs, then they will be converted to PDFs and then an XML will be created saying where that PDF is stored and will also stick in some meta data.

I'm just wondering: if the service is running and it is stopped in the middle of converting a load of documents - is it possible to allow it to keep processing until its current load is completed and then stop? Or will it just stop flat?

Comment: *is it possible to allow it to keep processing until its current load*  see [ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: It is entirely up to you to implement OnStop(), you can do whatever you want.  You don't even have to stop, but that's probably going to surprise the user a bit.  You've got up to 30 seconds before the service manager gets tired of waiting.